# What spells or abilities would a 17th level cleric use against a horde of demons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, encounter-design

I don't know much about clerics in 5e.  I've got a very powerful cleric and a bunch of soldiers (some decorative, some battle hardened) defending an underground temple from a horde of demons.  I'd like to make it clear that he went all-out before he died and potentially chose to die rather than let the demons into the sanctum.  He had time to prepare (days) and valuable materials (gems and so on).  What are some spells he could have used the traces of which the party will find as they venture into the desecrated sanctum?

Looking specifically for interesting or thoughtful uses of spells, long duration defense spells, buffs or combos I might overlook, etc.  Him just pulling out a warhammer and shooting some Beems or whatnot I can basically make up, however i'd like to tie it into 5e mechanics and if possible the kinds of combinations/optimization a player character cleric would use in that situation (and I don't know what those are).  Anything that would leave physical marks on the church that the players could Investigate is a plus.

As a side-note, I allow Detect Magic to detect traces of spells used in the past (forensic thaumatology), which is how I imagine the majority of this information is going to reach the PCs (they regularly do this).

Comment: This is probably a better fit for a forum, than for the Stack.

Comment: Is this a "heroic death of PC" situation or is this an NPC that did things, which means you could handwave some abilities as special if needed?